# Flutter question: How to insert a column inside a row in Flutter

Tags: flutter

My aim is to reproduce this UI layout in Flutter:
[image: Image of layout challenge]

So far I have produced a layout with the below code which is missing the green square below the yellow square in the middle of the screen. How can i include the green square below the yellow square and center them? Can this be done by inserting a column inside a row? Thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply wrap the inner container with a [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) widget.

Here you go

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center ,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 100.0,
                    height: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                    Container(
                    width: 100.0,
                    height: 100.0,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(DiceApp());

class DiceApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dice App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Text('2'),
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Text('2'),
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
              Container(
                width: 100,
                // alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('1'),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some insightful explanation as to what this code does, just for solution completeness.

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you the same layout shown in this example

[image]

```
                      // Scroll Area
                      child: ListTile(

                          // Horizontal Row
                          title: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[

                              // First element in Row
                              ImageIcon(
                                AssetImage("assets/images/my_photo.png"),
                              ),

                              // Second element in Row
                              Column(

                                children: [
                                  child: Text('My name'),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      child: Text('My title'),
                                    ],
                                      Image.asset(
                                        'assets/images/more.png',
                                      ),
                                  ),

                                ], // End of Column children

                              ), // End of Column

                            ], // End of Row children

                          ), // End of Row

                      ), // End of Scroll
```

Answer (score 0):

remember to add infinite height to the containers in red and blue
here is my flutter code that I made .

Create 04 containers and wrap the middle one in a column.

```
    body: SafeArea(
        child:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

      children: [
        Container(
          child: Text(' Container 1'),
          color: Colors.red,
          width: 100.0,
          height: double.infinity,

        ),

        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [

            Container(
              child: Text(' Container 2'),
              color: Colors.yellow,
              width: 100.0,
              height:100.0,

            ),
            Container(
              child: Text(' Container 3'),
              color: Colors.green,
              width: 100.0,
              height:100.0,

            ),


          ],
        ),

        Container(
          child: Text('Container 4'),
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: 100.0,
            height: double.infinity,

        )
      ],
    )),

  ),
);
```

}
}